# How do I get Intellisense (code completion) to work on VS.NET inside Parallels on a Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, parallels

How do I get Intellisense to work on Visual Studio running inside Parallels on a Mac?

On my PC I press CTRL+Space to get Intellisense, but inside Parallels it looks like no key combination works; I thought that maybe it's because Quicksilver or Spotlight were using the same key combinations and could be intercepting, but it still doesn't work after I've remapped those to use F keys.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few years old now, but I'll stick what I found here in case someone else finds it in a Google search.

I found I didn't have a problem until I swapped my Mac's Control and Command key's over so I only ever have to use Control+C, Control+V to copy and paste.

Once I swapped these over Control+Space wouldn't work in Visual Studio until I went to Parallels Preferences -> Keyboard and unchecked "Enable Mac OS X system shortcuts"

I'm guessing Cmd+Space or Ctrl+Space is some sort of Mac OS X shortcut, and it was overriding what I was typing in my windows machine.

Comment: I found the same thing - I really wish this would work, since other keys I want to go to OS X

Answer (score 1):

Use Fn+Ctrl+Space instead of Ctrl+Space in order to get Intellisense appear on Visual Studio running inside Parallels Desktop on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine. It's been a while since I used Parallels, but I'm sure there was an option to send "special" MacOS keys to the Virtual Machine, rather than to OSX - if you switch that on it should send everything to the VM.

If you are using it in Coherence mode then the only thing I can think of is change the keyboard mapping in Visual Studio (Tools, Options)

Answer (score 0):

Woks fine for me with Parallels 3.0 on my MacBook Pro.  I can click on a class, hit Ctrl-Space and it pops up Intellisense.  Works both in Coherence and Single Windows modes.  Typing a single character in whitespace brings it up as well.